# Distribution of $Y^2$ Problem, ($Y$ being uniform)

Tags: probability

Let Y a uniform r.v. on $[-1,1]$. Why doesn't this work to compute the distribution of $Y^2$ ?

$$E(y^2)=\int_{-1}^{1}y^2\frac{1}{2}dy=\int_0^1y^2dy$$

This calculation gives a distribution of $Y^2$ being a uniform on $[0,1]$ which is different from the actual distribution : $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}1_{[0,1]}(t)$

Answer (score 1):

$E[y^2]$ is the second moment of $Y$ and not it's distribution i.e. the mean of variable $Y^2$. to compute $f_{Y^2}(t)$ one possible way is to compute CDF of $Y^2$ , $F_{Y^2}(t)$ and then taking derivative with respect to $t$ like this:
$$F_{Y^2}(t)= P \{ Y^2 \le t \} =\begin{cases} 
0 \qquad \qquad \; \qquad if  \qquad t \le 0\\
 \frac{1}{2} \times 2\sqrt{t} \qquad   \quad if  \quad \quad 0 \le t \le 1 \\
1 \qquad \qquad \; \qquad if  \qquad 1 \le t 
\end{cases}$$ 
now taking derivative with respecto to $t$ gives the solution witch is  $f_{Y^2}(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}1_{[0,1]}(t)$. the second case is calculated like this:
$$P \{ Y^2 \le t \}=P \{ -\sqrt{t} \le Y \le \sqrt{t} \}= \int_{-\sqrt{t}}^{\sqrt{t}}\frac{1}{2}dt=\sqrt{t}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find the **distribution** of a transformation of a random variable, not the **expectation** of a function of a random variable.  You calculated $\operatorname{E}[Y^2]$ when what you are being asked to do is calculate $f_{Y^2}(y)$, or $F_{Y^2}(y) = \Pr[Y^2 \le y]$.

Comment: But $E(f(X))$ in general caracterises the distribution of $X$ right ? as this can be written as $E(f(X))=\int f(t) \phi_X(t) dt$ where $\phi_X$ being the density function for $X$

Comment: Yes but you want the distribution of $Y=X^2$. You could indeed calculate $E(f(Y))$. If you find something like $\int f(y)h(y)dy$ then $h$ is the density of $Y$.

Comment: @Augustin if you put $h(y)=\frac{1}{1-0}1_{[0,1]}$ and $f(y)=y^2$ this does work isn't it? which correponds to a Uniform on $[0,1]$. (Sorry i know i'm missing a point but can't see where)